# KVM Virtualization and Radius Authentication

Tags: linux-kvm, hotspot, radius, virt-manager

I've recently swapped my vms from Virtual Box to KVM. I am using virt-manager at the moment. I am happy with everything except for one problem. I am using NAT for vm networking. When the host is connecting to internet via a hot spot using radius authentication, guest cannot connect to internet. It seems the router drops the authentication after a few seconds.This was never the case with Virtual Box NAT.This would happen if I tried bridged networking in Virtual Box but not NAT. Is there any work around this?